# jQuery not getting proper div ID - works on most sites, but not on one

Tags: jquery

I have a WordPress plugin that I wrote.  I'm using it on several of my own websites with no problems, but one of the people that installed it is having an odd issue in the jQuery.  The issue is occurring before an AJAX call and hosing the call.

Example on his site: http://mediatechtorials.org/researching-basics/

Example on my site: http://www.onesixtyk.com/multi-video-box-test-page/

Starting on his site, scroll down to the video display area and click on the text in one of the tabs, the "processing" image appears and nothing else happens.  If you just click on the tab itself instead of the text, the new video appears properly.

On my sites, clicking anywhere in the tab, including on the text, makes the video load properly.

I'm using this code to get the ID of the tab that was clicked:

```
    var $clicked_tab = event.target.id;
```

He gave me access to his WP admin and I inserted some test code (I removed it so it's not on his live site).  On his site, when you click the text, event.target.id is blank.  On my site, it's the proper ID of the tab, e.g. "mvob-tab-1".  I've tried wrapping the text in another div with a different ID, but on his site, the event.target.id is still blank on clicking the text.

I tried installing the same plugins as he has.  I tried changing his theme.  Nothing made the code work properly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a debugger, you should see that his site has an unrelated script error, probably causing javascript to halt on the page. 
`Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'`

Comment: I get the identical error (infinite loading) on _both_ sites. No matter where I click (text or tab). FF 21.0 But I can confirm getting the error that @Ozzy noted.

Comment: I did some searching on the "toString" error and it looks like that's an issue with the video sites.  It only happens on some of the videos I've used for testing (most, actually, but a few from Vimeo don't throw that error).

Comment: zsawyer, When you get a chance, can you test here (http://www.nuttymango.com/plugindevelopment/mvob-test-page/) and see if you get the infinite loading issue?  I'm also using FF 21.0 and everything loads fine on my sites.  It also looks like Vevo videos are the ones that don't throw the "toString" error.  "Around The World" is from Vevo and when loading that one, there's no error.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var $clicked_tab = event.target.id;
```

to:

```
var $clicked_tab = event.currentTarget.id;
```

`event.target.id` is the `<strong>` element that wraps the text (and doesn't have an `id` attribute). `event.currentTarget` is always the `<div>` element (in this case) and has an `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Pete!  I changed that.  I haven't confirmed on the user's site yet to see if it works.  He seems to have a lot going on with his site, so I'm not real sure if the issue is actually in my plugin yet.